# Mi app no funciona después de compilarla con Phonegap Build

Tags: android, phonegap

Buenos Días!
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con phonegap.
Se  trata de  una app que lee códigos qr (plugin barcodescanner) y envía una petición por ajax a un server (empleando jQuery).

Conectándome con el móvil al pc donde estoy desarrollándola, me funciona perfectamente (hemos probado en varios móviles android) pero cuando la hemos generado en release a través de phonegap build, no funciona.

Cómo debería funcionar:
Se abre una pantalla con un boton que inicia el lector de qr, cuando se lée el código, se envía el parámetro leído a un servidor (ajax) y este devuelve datos(nombre  y apellidos). Estos datos son mostrados en unos div que al principio estaban ocultos(jQuery).

Cómo funciona tras compilar:
Se abre la pantalla, y aparece el div (que en principio debería estár oculto) y el botón que inicia el lector de QR no hace nada...

[image: Durante el desarrollo]

[image: Después de Phonegap Build]

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Porque no revisas el log. Puedes realizar debugging para determinar el problema..

Comment: Y cómo hago para ver el log o el debugging desde la app ya instalada en el dispositivo?

Answer (score 1):

Esto me pasó a mi, y es por la versión del plugin de phonegap. Si te fijas, cuando estas haciendo el build, si abres el log de el phonegap build te darás cuenta de que no llega a compilar el plugin en android, da error, lo sé porque a mi también me paso. Tienes que definir la versión a usar del plugin, y utiliza la 6 que es la que me funcionó a mi, si tienes mas dudas preguntame y te responderé.

Por cierto, ese diseño como lo has logrado?

La solución se encuentra en el config.xml . Elimina la linea donde defines que utilizarás el plugin de barcode scanner, y utiliza esta:
 `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="6.0.0" />` . 
Es importante utilizar esta, ya que si no el compilador da error, y solo lo hace con Android.

Comment: Debes ser mas concreto en tu respuesta, incluso estando en lo cierto, no debieras basar la solución en una experiencia previa. Incluye el motivo, trazas, referencias y define en que versiones y/o entorno la solución es aplicable. Por último, no realices una pregunta al OP en tu respuesta que pudiera abrir otro hilo. Un saludo

Comment: @DavidIsla La experiencia lo es todo, y este fallo es reciente. La solución se encuentra en el config.xml . Elimina la linea donde defines que utilizarás el plugin de barcode scanner, y utiliza esta: 
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="6.0.0" />  . Es importante utilizar esta, ya que si no el compilador da error, y solo lo hace con Android.

Comment: Incluye toda esta información en tu respuesta, no es para mi, es para el OP ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @alexdemons2000 . Me ha solventado el problema el hecho de cambiar la versión del plugin.

Comment: Me alegro de que sea asi! Yo llegue a compilar la app unas 30 veces hasta darme cuenta :S